# remove rows of dates and duplicate dates for any date that has an NA

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm looking to remove all dates that have any NAs/missing data for any observation type, from a `data.frame` that has duplicate dates. For example, here I'd like to end up with a `data.frame` of just three rows with `2018-12-05` data.  My non-example `data.frame` is quite long, so I'm leaning toward run time over readability, if there are a few ways, and I'm open to `tidyverse` and non-tidyverse ways.

```
date_time <- rep(seq(from=as.POSIXct("2018-12-01", tz="GMT"), 
             to=as.POSIXct("2018-12-05", tz="GMT"), by="1 day"),3)
value     <- c(1,2,NA,NA,5,NA,NA,NA,4,5,7,NA,NA,NA,8)
class     <- c(rep("a", 5), rep("b", 5), rep("c", 5))
df        <- data.frame(date_time, value, class)
```

from:

[image]

filtered to:

[image]

Comment: See `?na.omit()` or specific columns with `df[!is.na(var),]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within some `dplyr` functions, you can use the base `all`. Group by date, then find whether all values for each group are non-`NA`.

With some extra steps to illustrate:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  arrange(date_time, class) %>%
  group_by(date_time) %>%
  mutate(all_vals = all(!is.na(value))) %>%
  filter(all_vals)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#> # Groups:   date_time [1]
#>   date_time           value class all_vals
#>   <dttm>              <dbl> <fct> <lgl>   
#> 1 2018-12-05 00:00:00     5 a     TRUE    
#> 2 2018-12-05 00:00:00     5 b     TRUE    
#> 3 2018-12-05 00:00:00     8 c     TRUE
```

Or more briefly, find the non-`NA`s within `filter`:

```r
df %>%
  group_by(date_time) %>%
  filter(all(!is.na(value)))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#> # Groups:   date_time [1]
#>   date_time           value class
#>   <dttm>              <dbl> <fct>
#> 1 2018-12-05 00:00:00     5 a    
#> 2 2018-12-05 00:00:00     5 b    
#> 3 2018-12-05 00:00:00     8 c
```

<sup>Created on 2018-12-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

If you need speed, I don't know. But the following function keeps only the rows where the dates have all values of `class`.

```
fun <- function(DF){
  DF2 <- DF[!is.na(DF$value), ]
  u <- unique(DF2$class)
  sp <- split(DF2, DF2$date_time)
  inx <- sapply(sp, function(d){
    all(u %in% d$class)
  })
  DF2 <- do.call(rbind, sp[inx])
  row.names(DF2) <- NULL
  DF2
}

fun(df)
#   date_time value class
#1 2018-12-05     5     a
#2 2018-12-05     5     b
#3 2018-12-05     8     c
```

**Edit.**
Here is a comparative speed test. [Camille's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53574500/remove-rows-of-dates-and-duplicate-dates-for-any-date-that-has-an-na/53575097#53575097) is faster for larger dataframes, where speed is more important. And is nicer.

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

fun2 <- function(DF){
  DF %>%
    arrange(date_time, class) %>%
    group_by(date_time) %>%
    mutate(all_vals = all(!is.na(value))) %>%
    filter(all_vals)
}

mb <- microbenchmark(
  rui = fun(df),
  camille = fun2(df)
)
mb1 <- microbenchmark(
  rui = fun(df1),
  camille = fun2(df1)
)

ap <- autoplot(mb)
ap1 <- autoplot(mb1)
cowplot::plot_grid(ap, ap1)
```

[image]

Comment: useful for sure, but I'm still unable to filter my `data.frame` properly (getting it down to 3 rows only).

Comment: @doconnor So you have a problem of `NA`'s **and** a problem of duplicated dates?

Comment: the duplicate dates aren't a problem, I just want a `data.frame` of the same three columns for the dates that have a value (observation) for each class. Only Dec. 5 has a value for class a,b & c.

Comment: @doconnor OK, I think I've got it now. The code was completely changed, see the new one.

Comment: fantastic. I wish I saved your nice `microbenchmark` example/plots to test yours vs @camille's methods on my actual data.